How to move nested files recursively
I have a folder, app, which is supposed to have import and export folders containing files like so:
$ tree
app
├── export
│   ├── some-unique-filename
│   ├── another-unique-filename
│   └── ...
└── import
    ├── some-unique-filename
    ├── another-unique-filename
    └── ...

However, due to an rsync script error (now corrected) we've ended up with the app folder being copied into itself, perhaps hundreds of times!
So right now we have this:
$ tree
app
├── app
│   ├── app
│   │   └── ... etc. 
│   ├── export
│   │   └── another-unique-filename
│   └── import
│       └── another-unique-filename
├── export
│   └── some-unique-filename
└── import
    └── some-unique-filename

How can I fix the current nested-folder structure back to the desired only-one-app folder structure?

This have nothing to do on a programming Q/A website. But this is what you need: cd app; rsync -avP app/app/ .; rm -ri app/app 

Why do you need to move anything? It looks like you just need to remove the extra nested directories. So just rm -r app/app

A script like this should do it, from the root:
mkdir -p new/export
mkdir -p new/import

# Or use cp - to have the option to try again if you make a mistake
mv app/**/export/* new/export 
mv app/**/import/* new/import

The double star matches zero or more directories and subdirectories, taking care of the recursive folder structure for you.
Dealing with deeply nested folders
If as you say there are 100s of folders that may error, in which case an alternative is to use find with exec instead:
mkdir -p new/export
mkdir -p new/import

# Or use cp - to have the option to try again if you make a mistake
find app -type f -path '*/export/*' -exec mv {} $PWD/new/export/ \;
find app -type f -path '*/import/*' -exec mv {} $PWD/new/import/ \;

This finds the files recursively under the top-level app folder, and moves them to new/export and new/import (using $PWD to get an absolute path).
Cleaning up
Once you're happy with the results - clean up the unwanted folders:
rm -rf app
mv new app

